# types/d3-array is giving type error error

Tags: angular, typescript

ERROR in node_modules/@types/d3-array/index.d.ts:36:103 - error TS2574: A rest element type must be an array type.

36 export type NestedInternMap<TObject, TReduce, TKeys extends unknown[]> = TKeys extends [infer TFirst, ...infer TRest]

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~10.0.0",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^10.0.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^10.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
    "d3": "^7.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "lint-staged": "^12.1.2",
    "prettier-plugin-organize-imports": "^2.3.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.5",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.17.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1000.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/d3": "^7.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.37",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0-next.1",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^2.0.1",
    "husky": "^7.0.4",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15",
    "prettier": "^2.5.1",
    "pretty-quick": "^3.1.2",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.18.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.5",
    "webpack": "^4.6.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1"
  }
}
```